# CSS Styling for IPAD not working

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, ipad

**Problem:** I have the following styling that targets mobile phones for the footer:

```
@media (max-width: 800px){
    #footer-affiliation { 
        background-color: #0077C0; 
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
        padding: 5px;
        height:110px;


        width:109.01% !important;
        margin-left:-15px;
        }
}
```

However, it affects the footer on the IPAD. I did the following to target only IPAD's and IPhones. For the iphone css styling works fine, however for the IPAD styling is not working:

```
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 480px) 
    and (max-device-width : 800px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) {
     #footer-affiliation { 
        background-color: #0077C0; 
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
        padding: 5px;
        height:110px;


        width:104% !important;
        margin-left:-15px;
    }
}
```

I would like to know what other approach I can do to target IPAD's only.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

For targeting iPad use following media query

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
  /* For general iPad layouts */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* For portrait layouts only */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* For landscape layouts only */
}
```

Detailed info available in this site for various device in iPad

[CSS media Queries for iPad](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/)